# How to hide cmake compiler definitions -D from printing in the terminal

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options, cmake-language

I have hundreds of compiler definitions added using add_compile_definitions(var=value......) to my root CMakeLists.txt which gets printed out in the commandline/terminal with -Dvar=value during build. I want to turn off the echo to hide the prints from my terminal window. So far I have tried using

```
 1. set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE OFF) 
 2. set(CMAKE_NO_VERBOSE)
 3. cmake.definitions["CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE"] = False (in conanfile)
 4. cmake.verbose = False (in conanfile)
```

but none helped, although CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE in cmakecache.txt sets to False, CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL somehow gets set to 1, also changing this var to "0" in the cache for debugging did not help......does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Add the complete cmake file and output.

Comment: "CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL somehow gets set to 1" - This means that given variable is set somewhere in your code. You need to find that setting and remove it.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev to test if its set somewhere i have unset the var in my cmakecache.txt and tried to build but it still gives me the print of all the definitions

Comment: Please, prepare [mcve] for reproduce the problem.